# Website works on All browsers including IE9 but not on lower versions of IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have developed this [WEBSITE](http://www.demadeiraboards.co.uk/viessmann-rhi/blue/calculator.html) but the javascript wont work on Versions lower than < IE9

IE shows an error message on 2 of my javascript files(please find below)

## re.js (Line 386)

Link to code [HERE](http://pastebin.com/W6JBLjhk)

## holder.js(Line 316)

Link to code [HERE](http://pastebin.com/jAC2sgrb)

I have been fighting over this quite a while now and I have not found any solution.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Please visit the link so you can inspect error(use IE version < 9)

All the rest browsers(Including Android and IOS mobile browsers) work fine with no problems at all!

Comment: In IE 8 window.Node is null and not a function, not sure why? Any pointers?